# Android: saving data with relation Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a database on Parse.com. There is a table called EventsUsers that contains eventId as string and userId as pointer on user everything looks like this:

```
eventId : eventId,
userId : {
  __type : "Pointer",
  className : "_User",
  objectId : userId
}
```

I need to create row in this table, but I don't know how to create the pointer. 
This is what I have done yet, it creates the row without the pointer.

```
ParseObject po = new ParseObject("EventsUsers");
po.put("eventId", event.getId());
po.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it like this, an example with current user.

```
ParseObject po = new ParseObject("EventsUsers"); 
po.put("eventId", event.getId()); 
po.put("userid",ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
po.saveInBackground();
```

Hope this helps :)